# I got sh: latex: command not found error when try to text latex and manim

Tags: manim

> $ python3 -m manim example_scenes.py WriteStuff -pl

```
Media will be written to /Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/media/. You can change this behavior with the --media_dir flag.
```

**sh: latex: command not found**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/manimlib/extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "/Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "example_scenes.py", line 100, in construct
    example_text = TextMobject(
  File "/Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/manimlib/mobject/svg/tex_mobject.py", line 147, in __init__
    SingleStringTexMobject.__init__(
  File "/Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/manimlib/mobject/svg/tex_mobject.py", line 42, in __init__
    file_name = tex_to_svg_file(
  File "/Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/manimlib/utils/tex_file_writing.py", line 21, in tex_to_svg_file
    dvi_file = tex_to_dvi(tex_file)
  File "/Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/manimlib/utils/tex_file_writing.py", line 69, in tex_to_dvi
    raise Exception(
Exception: Latex error converting to dvi. See log output above or the log file: /Users/pi/Documents/ManimInstall/manim/media/Tex/c0bd21d57323a926.log
```

Comment: Please explain what you have tried with a short sentence and try not to make it harder for other people helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install Latex?

The error

```sh
sh: latex: command not found
```

says that manim tries, to find `latex` but couldn't find it. Possibly you may not have installed latex.

Assuming you are on Ubuntu or Debian, run,

```sh
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

to install latex and things should work then.

Answer (score 0):

from here https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/1661

add latex path to environment variable (mac):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin:$PATH"
```